# Select option from bootstrap dropdown, that option reveals more/hidden content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a drop down that upon selecting a certain option (yes) it reveals more content. I tried to do this using the bootstrap accordion functionality without success. I've created a bootply of the drop down and the accordion, just as an example of how I want it to work. http://bootply.com/64676 - So, click 'Yes' in the drop down list and an accordion opens underneath with content related to that answer.

```
<label>Do you have any children?</label>
<select>
    <option>Select:</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>

<!-- Example of how I want the above working -->
<p>Name of your hotel - <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#hotel">Why do we need this?</a>
</p>

<!-- Popup hidden content -->
<div id="hotel" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="alert">
            <h4>Content here!</h4>

        <p>blurb - how many?</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should check for your options value attribute, I put the example here http://jsfiddle.net/bnJvG/

```
<label>Do you have any children?</label>
<select name="children">
    <option value="">Select:</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<div id="hotel" for-field="children" for-value="yes" class="accordion-body collapse">TEST</div>
```

And de JS

```
$('select[name="children"]').change(function(event){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var value = selected.attr("value");
    var name=  $(this).attr("name");
    var selector = '[for-field="'+name+'"]';
    $('.accordion-body'+selector).addClass('collapse');
    var selectorForValue = selector+'[for-value="'+value+'"]';
    var selectedPanel = $('.accordion-body'+ selectorForValue  );
    selectedPanel.removeClass('collapse');
})
```